# regex expression to parse logs

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

Hello hackers wonder if anyone can help out i need to match all types of logs with pattern any suggestions on how to match full object in {} ?

Sample

```
[1517725731.300][DEBUG]: DEVTOOLS EVENT Runtime.consoleAPICalled {
   "args": [ {
      "className": "Array",
      "description": "Array(2)",
      "objectId": "{\"injectedScriptId\":13,\"id\":11}",
      "preview": {
         "description": "Array(2)",
         "overflow": false,
         "properties": [ {
            "name": "0",
            "type": "string",
            "value": "tracking fired"
         }, {
            "name": "1",
            "subtype": "array",
            "type": "object",
            "value": "Arguments(4)"
         } ],
         "subtype": "array",
         "type": "object"
      },
      "subtype": "array",
      "type": "object"
   } ],
   "executionContextId": 13,
   "stackTrace": {
      "callFrames": [ {
         "columnNumber": 39,
         "functionName": "window.debug.that.(anonymous function)",
         "lineNumber": 184,
         "scriptId": "234",
         "url": "https://secure.somerandomsite.com/js/common/ba-debug.js"
      }, {
         "columnNumber": 475,
         "functionName": "loggerTrackingHandler",
         "lineNumber": 0,
         "scriptId": "60",
         "url": "https://secure.somerandomsite.com/jsmin/gzip_1642294/bundles/mainTracking.min.js"
      }, {
         "columnNumber": 436,
         "functionName": "CsApplicationTrackingControllerBase.commontTrackEvent",
         "lineNumber": 4,
         "scriptId": "60",
         "url": "https://secure.somerandomsite.com/jsmin/gzip_1642294/bundles/mainTracking.min.js"
      }, {
         "columnNumber": 5,
         "functionName": "CsApplicationTrackingControllerBase.parentTrackEvent",
         "lineNumber": 8,
         "scriptId": "60",
         "url": "https://secure.somerandomsite.com/jsmin/gzip_1642294/bundles/mainTracking.min.js"
      }, {
         "columnNumber": 525,
         "functionName": "CsApplicationTrackingController.trackEvent",
         "lineNumber": 16,
         "scriptId": "60",
         "url": "https://secure.somerandomsite.com/jsmin/gzip_1642294/bundles/mainTracking.min.js"
      }, {
         "columnNumber": 2124,
         "functionName": "CsApplicationTrackingController.trackChangeTab",
         "lineNumber": 19,
         "scriptId": "60",
         "url": "https://secure.somerandomsite.com/jsmin/gzip_1642294/bundles/mainTracking.min.js"
      }, {
         "columnNumber": 22,
         "functionName": "MyCreditAnalysisViewModel.self.selectTab",
         "lineNumber": 6,
         "scriptId": "263",
         "url": "https://secure.somerandomsite.com/jsmin/gzip_N1393604112/bundles/newOverview.min.js"
      }, {
         "columnNumber": 48,
         "functionName": "",
         "lineNumber": 53,
         "scriptId": "281",
         "url": "https://secure.somerandomsite.com/js/common/knockout/knockout-2.1.0.js"
      }, {
         "columnNumber": 4815,
         "functionName": "dispatch",
         "lineNumber": 2,
         "scriptId": "228",
         "url": "https://secure.somerandomsite.com/3rd_party/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"
      }, {
         "columnNumber": 708,
         "functionName": "i",
         "lineNumber": 2,
         "scriptId": "228",
         "url": "https://secure.somerandomsite.com/3rd_party/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"
      } ]
   },
   "timestamp": 1517725731298.069,
   "type": "log"
}
[1517725731.305][DEBUG]: DEVTOOLS RESPONSE Input.dispatchMouseEvent (id=260) {

}
[1517725731.305][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1517725731.305][DEBUG]: DEVTOOLS COMMAND Runtime.evaluate (id=261) {
   "expression": "1"
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to match? Any object in the "args" list?

Comment: yes that is correct everything after [1517725731.300][DEBUG]: DEVTOOLS EVENT Runtime.consoleAPICalled  ->> {....}

Comment: Then edit your question to make it clearer, also the last lines of your logs isn't properly formatted.

Comment: But to answer your question, it's probably impossible or very complex to parse JSON using regex, in addition to being very inefficient. You'd have more luck using a JSON library to parse your log.

Comment: Google `jsonschema2pojo`, enter your JSON data there and have it generate code for you. Don't try to do something with regexes for which better solutions exist.

Comment: Thanks gentleman, now that i got some response i believe, the question i asked should have been structured differently. What i am trying to do is sink logs via fluentd to elastic-search. the problem is logs are non standard and on top of that printed with something like pretty print. [link](https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/articles/parser_regexp) i was trying to use the following config to match the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Any line starting with something like `[1517725731.305][INFO]:` is a new log entry. Look for those.

```
public static void processLogFile(Path logFile) throws IOException {
    Pattern logstart = Pattern.compile("^\\[\\d+\\.\\d+\\]\\[\\w+\\]: ");
    try (BufferedReader log = Files.newBufferedReader(logFile)) {
        StringBuilder logEntry = new StringBuilder();
        for (String line; (line = log.readLine()) != null; ) {
            if (logstart.matcher(line).find()) {
                if (logEntry.length() != 0)
                    processLogEntry(logEntry.toString());
                logEntry.setLength(0); // clear buffer
            }
            logEntry.append(line).append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        if (logEntry.length() != 0)
            processLogEntry(logEntry.toString());
    }
}
private static void processLogEntry(String logEntry) {
    // code here
}
```